# RoR: Search Logic, How do I use OR with two different values on the same field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, searchlogic

I want to do something similar to :
@search(some_condition or some_other_condition)

this is how the internet says to use OR http://www.binarylogic.com/2009/08/26/using-searchlogic-to-combine-named-scopes-with-or/

unfortunately it only uses the same value for two fields.

So.. IS there a way to do @search.(some_field == value OR other_field == other_value) ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Don't resort to searchlogic for the or part, just use ruby.

```
result = @search.first_name_like('The') || @search.last_name_like('LindyHop')
```

Is there a reason that I'm not following as to why you can't do it like this?

Comment: yeah, because I'me using search logic for pagination as well (w/ will_paginate).   example:     @people = @search.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)

Comment: Could you not paginate over `result` in my suggested answer? I don't remember how will_paginate works exactly.

Comment: you updated  your answer or it looks different from how I last saw it. But doing || with the SearchLogic object should work.